# Android UI Tools

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please give me an idea about android User interface design.Is there any tool to design the User Interface? Or Is we need to create XML file manually ? I am really newbie in android application?

Thanks

Comment: For the design side of things rather than strictly implementation, see these two Google I/O talks: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html (from 2010, general design patterns) http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/designing-and-implementing-android-uis-for-phones-and-tablets.html (from 2011, covers UIs for phones and tablets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to install the Android sdk, eclipse and ADT(Android development tools) plugin to eclipse and see for yourself. All the information about how to do this is on [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).

If you are a beginner I can also recommend you what I think to be the best android development tutorial on the web, the free best one at least, from [Marakana](http://www.youtube.com/user/MarakanaTechTV#grid/user/E953C0B85B50AB62).

I think this will tell you all you need to start...

EDIT: I had no time to give a greater answer, so I'm completing it now.
Google has made a big effort to provide a WYSIWYG interface to avoid xml but you will still need to code some stuff. Another great help to avoid xml is the Properties view on eclipse accessible by Window > Show View > Properties or if its not there look for it in the Window > Show View > Other... popup menu. The Outline view accessible through the same menus will help you select between the elements you have on your layout.

All these things combined with the eclipse auto-completion feature and some shortcuts(ctrl + space is your friend) while coding in xml will give you a lot of information about the properties available.

If you are really in the mood to start developing to the android platform the Marakana Android Bootcamp I linked above is going to teach you all the basic stuff and mainly the background you need to look for what you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Droid Draw: http://www.droiddraw.org/ is one option.

The ADK currently comes with a plugin for Eclipse that lets you do this.

Google has plans to enhance this feature: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq05KqjXTvs&feature=channel_video_title

Answer (score 2):

On July 6th, version 12 of the ADT (Android Developer Tools) was released and Google has made some big changes to creating RelativeLayout with a WYSIWYG editor.  You can check it out around the 26 minute mark of the video posted below.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq05KqjXTvs